# cPickle cannot write methods

Tags: python, pickle

I try to dump a class

```
class ClassificationStatistic(object):     
 def __init__(self):
        self.tp = 0
        self.fp = 0
        self.tn = 0
        self.fn = 0
        self.failedtoparseinput = 0
        self.processed = 0
 def add_sample(self,file,calc_verdict):
    bla-bla-bla
 def merge(self,another):
    bla-bla-bla
 def results(self):
    bla-bla-bla

file = open('test.tmp','wb')            
cPickle.dump(ClassificationStatistic(),file)
file.close()
```

This class have three methods (`add_sample`,`merge`,`results`), but if I try to dump it they absensed in `test.tmp` why? There are no words as (`add_sample`,`merge`,`results`) at that file.

Comment: Why would there be methods in the file? The pickle library serialize the data, not the byte code.

Comment: And is there a method to serialize bytecode in python?

Comment: read this for pickle limitation on serialization: https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled. Personnaly I have never serialize byte codes but marshal seems to be what you need: https://docs.python.org/2/library/marshal.html. I am not sure marshal is the solution for you but you should have a look at it.

Comment: the package `dis` and `byteplay` could be usefull for you as well I think: http://akaptur.github.io/blog/2013/08/14/python-bytecode-fun-with-dis/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cPickle doesn't serialize the methods because it doesn't need to. It records that the object is an instance of `ClassificationStatistic`, and that's enough to tell what methods it has. In fact, the instance doesn't have any method objects on it to pickle; they're created on the fly when accessed, and they're never stored on the instance itself.